How can I configure ssh agent in expo's eas?
My project depends on a module stored in a private GitHub repo. and it's downloaded via ssh (git+ssh://git@github.com...). How can I configure eas build to setup an ssh-agent to facilitate this download when installing dependencies on the eas servers?
I use this for GitHub actions.
